# Reading a file with input values and making a .out with the results

Tags: java, linux, unit-testing, testing

I have this Java file that takes in two ints from the user and it prints out the sum of the numbers, this file is called JavaAdd.java . To test this file, I would need to make a file that can contain possible testing numbers, called JavaAddTest. When I create a the JavaAddTest, the first line looks like:

`2 2`

and when I run the script:

`java JavaAdd < JavaAddTest`

I get the output to the console:

```
Please input 2 ints:
The sum of the 2 values are: 4
```

which is what I want. But I want to be able to populate JavaAddTest with a set of numbers like:

```
2 2
0 2
-2 -2
10 10
```

and be able to get an output like:

```
Please input 2 ints:
The sum of the 2 values are: 4
Please input 2 ints:
The sum of the 2 values are: 2
Please input 2 ints:
The sum of the 2 values are: -4
Please input 2 ints:
The sum of the 2 values are: 20
```

Hoe can I do this in a linux environment? What would I have to do the JavaAddTest in order for it to be able to read all of my inputs?

Comment: can u post your code for JavaAddTest

Comment: it is just a file containing  these values
2 2
0 2
-2 -2
10 10

Comment: oh sorry, I mean the code that is actually doing the calculation

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaAdd {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please input 2 numbers");
  int num1 = sc.nextInt();
  int num2 = sc.nextInt();
  int sum = num1+num2;
  System.out.println("The sum of the two values are: " + sum);
 }
 
}

Comment: keep doing what you're doing, but add a for loop that does the calculation until the end of the file using sc.hasNextInt(), and then print it out.

Answer (score 0):

[JUnit tutorial link -> see Parameterized test in it for Junit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)

```
public class JavaAdd {

public void add(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("The sum is " + (a + b));
}
}
```

Junit class

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class JavaAddTest {

int a, b;

public JavaAddTest(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection addNumberInfo() {
 // if you want to read the numbers from file.

 // read here and create array and return it.


    return Arrays
            .asList(new Integer[][] { { 2, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 19, 5 }, { 22, 6 }, { 23, 7 } });
}

@Test
public void testAdd() {
    JavaAdd add = new JavaAdd();
    add.add(a, b);
}

}
```

output of the following code

```
The sum is 4
The sum is 7
The sum is 24
The sum is 28
The sum is 30
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I would need to read input from a different file hence the JavaAddTest file, not have the testing right on the java file

Comment: read the file in junit method addNumberInfo and pass the values to array and finally return it. Your purpose will be solved.